# How to close the Navbar when clicked outside?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i am trying to create a hamburger menu. I have got the opening part of the menu to work but there is a problem with closing it.

I have added an event listener which checks if the event.target is equal to navbar but the problem is that it doesn't close the navbar and doesn't even let me open it. Here's my code:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    const nav = document.getElementById('nav-container')
    if(e.target != nav){
    
      nav.classList.remove('show')
    }
  })

//Navbar opening function

  function showNav(){
    const nav = document.getElementById('nav-container')

    nav.classList.add('show')
  }
```

Comment: it depends a lot on the way you constructed the HTML of your Nav

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
// Declare your DOM elements once at the top
const nav = document.getElementById('nav-container');
const burger = document.getElementById('burger');

burger.addEventListener('click', showNav);

function showNav(e){
  nav.classList.add('show');
  // Prevent the click from propagating and immediatly closing the navbar again
  e.stopPropagation();
  // Listen for clicks on the document
  document.addEventListener('click', navCloseListener);
}

function hideNav(){
  nav.classList.remove('show');
  // Stop listening for clicks on the document
  document.removeEventListener('click', navCloseListener);
}

function navCloseListener(e) {
  // If the target is not the nav itself nor contained within it
  if(!nav.contains(e.target)) {
    hideNav();
  }
}
```

```css
body { background: #eee }
nav { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 200px; height: 100vh; background: white }
nav:not(.show) { display: none }
```

```html
<nav id="nav-container">
  <ul>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<button id="burger">Burger</button>
```